# Moss Sub sites navigation elements

Tags: sharepoint, navigation, nodes

My site structure looks like this:

```
- top-level site
--sub-site
---page
---page
--sub-site
---page
```

I want to disable the link on the tab of each sub-site that currently links to default.aspx so that it acts as a heading to the pages only and not a url that can be clicked. When users navigate over the sub-site tab, the pages drop down menu displays.

Would I need to code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding it would make it easier as it would give you more control over the html. It is not a massive job to create a custom navigation provider and include it in your masterpage/page layouts.

[This is a reasonable introduction to your options](http://blogs.msdn.com/modonovan/archive/2008/05/30/custom-navigation-in-sharepoint-the-full-monty.aspx).

I personally have found the code [released here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2006/12/02/customizing-the-wss-3-0-moss-2007-menu-control.aspx) by the SharePoint team to have been very useful.